# checked text view doesn't check

Tags: android, listview

I created a custom list view that displays a name and has a check next to it. I decided not to go with using a checkbox but instead use checked text view. The problem is when I click on the row, the check does not light up. I was wondering how I could fix this problem. This is the layout for my list view, each element will have a checked text view with differing text. I also need a way to scroll through the list and whichever element is unchecked should have its text greyed out.
Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <CheckedTextView android:text="CheckedTextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark" android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"></CheckedTextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT Here is the code that my list view goes through

```
 static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

private void refreshList(String id, ListView lv) {
    // removes the list and rebuilds it will choose different response
    // string to get the refreshed times.

    try {
        HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://iphone-radar.com/accounts/"+id);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            String response = client1.execute(request, responseHandler);



        list.removeAll(list);
        SpecialAdapter adapter = new SpecialAdapter(this, list,
                R.layout.trackingme_row_layout, new String[] { "name" },
                new int[] { R.id.checkedTextView1 });

        org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray tracking_users = obj.getJSONArray("d");

        for (int i = 0; i < tracking_users.length(); i++) {

            HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject user = tracking_users.getJSONObject(i);
            temp.put("name", user.getString("full_name"));
            // upload location time

            list.add(temp);

        }
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Here is the special adapter that it goes through so that every other row is either white or grey.

```
 public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
private int[] colors = new int[]{R.drawable.row_background_grey,       R.drawable.row_background_white};

public SpecialAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list, int resource,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, list, resource, from, to);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    view.setBackgroundResource(colors[colorPos]);
    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I got you want to have multiple CheckedTextView's in your list.

Below you find one approach to solve this problem. As the ListView is reusing views we need a way to keep track of the different CheckedTextView's, hence the use of HashMaps. An alternative way would be to just keep track of the states and with an OnItemClickListener change the state and then update the entire list.

```
public class CheckedTextViewExample extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {   

    // store CheckTextView's
    private HashMap<Integer, CheckedTextView> mCheckedList = 
            new HashMap<Integer, CheckedTextView>();
    // store state
    private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mIsChecked = 
            new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    // the list objects
    private ArrayList<MyObject> mList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

        MyObject one = new MyObject();
        one.setName("One");
        ...
        MyObject thirteen = new MyObject();
        thirteen.setName("thirteen");
        mList.add(one);
        ...
        mList.add(thirteen);        

        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mList));        
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // get the CheckedTextView
        CheckedTextView ct = mCheckedList.get(v.getTag());
        if (ct != null) {
            // change the state and colors
            ct.toggle();
            if (ct.isChecked()) {
                ct.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                ct.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
            // add current state to map
            mIsChecked.put((Integer) v.getTag(), ct.isChecked());
        }       
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {

        private ArrayList<MyObject> items;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<MyObject> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            CheckedTextView ct = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
            ct.setText(items.get(position).getName());
            if (mIsChecked.get(position) != null) {
                if (mIsChecked.get(position)) {
                    ct.setChecked(true);
                    ct.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    ct.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
            }
            // tag it
            ct.setTag(position);
            mCheckedList.put(position, ct);
            ct.setOnClickListener(CheckedTextViewExample.this);

            return view;
        }
    }

    private class MyObject {
        private String name;    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

I posted the eclipse project on my [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20121120010230/http://www.rochdev.com:80/2011/08/checkedtextview.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment but for now I'd prefer to not extend listactivity. My listview does something similar to what you did. my special adapter does @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  int colorPos = position % colors.length;
  view.setBackgroundResource(colors[colorPos]);
  return view;
 } to change the colors, can you help me alter my code so that I can make my checkbox light up? Thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be any big changes. Easiest would be if you add the code for your class to your main post.

Comment: I edited my original post. It is pretty similar to your answer and im pretty sure the only part i need to change is in my custom list adapter class. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: I tried your code and I only end up with two words (one and thirteen) in a list with white text (clicking does nothing). I'm a bit confused about how to keep track of the position of the check box

Comment: Well, the example above wont do much else. Except highlighting of the checkboxes and change the text color :) Above you will find a link to an example I posted on my blog together with some images and complete source code.

Comment: Wow, that blog helped me out a lot. If I wanted to change the background of the individual items would I do something like this  LayoutInflater vi = 
                    (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null); view.setbackground("some color")? I'm trying to use your method but also keep the functionality of my special adapter to alternate background colors as well

Comment: Yes, pretty much. You can for example: Declare the colors in your adapter - private String[] colors = {"#348283", "#853832"}; - then use what you did before with - int colorPos = position % colors.length; view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[colorPos])); 
I've updated the blog post too.

Answer (score 2):

performClick method is not override for CheckedTextView as done for CompoundButton.
So following code would do:

```
        final CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView1);
        checkedTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkedTextView.toggle();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, I added this to my code and it gave me a source not found error

Comment: Please explain more or give us the stack trace.

Comment: May be you have to add import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Could you give me the stack trace, or let me know in which line you are geting NullPointerException.

Comment: I am now doing something a bit differently, After I click the list item I want the specific checkedtextview to show up so I set this upprotected void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
 CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView1);
checkedTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    ((CheckedTextView) arg0).toggle();
   }
  });
 }  But for some reason it doesn't work right until I click it a few times. By the way it crashed on the setonclicklistener line